# Can not see package javax.sound.sampled in NetBeans

Tags: java, audio, netbeans, package

I am a novice in Java. I am using NetBeans IDE to edit and compile test applications. Everything looks ok, but I can not add and compile package javax.sound.sampled in my application. NetBeans underscored it and write "package javax.sound.sampled does not exist".

I have installed last version of JDK (v.1.6_35) but nothing happens. I also read that javax.sound.sampled is embedded into JDK so it doesn't need to download any plugins, but I even can't found any files like "javax" into installed JDK package (i mean C:/Program Files/Java folder).

What I am doing wrong??

Comment: only that package is missing? or other packages too?

Comment: Thank you, Denis, problem was in small characters used in subclasses names (for example javax.sound.sampled.audioformat.encoding.PCM_SIGNED instead of javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED). So NetBeans underscored whole package name.

Comment: good for you! ps. try to refrain for using russian here, some people might not like it ;)

Answer (score 4):

In your code replace

```
import javax.sound.sampled;
```

to

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
```